# Form_For Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Here is my form on my show page for the holders controller:

```
<%= form_for(question) do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :question %>
        <%= f.text_field :question,  :cols => 125, :rows => 4  %>

        <%= f.label :answer %>
        <%= f.text_field :answer,  :cols => 140 %>

        <%= f.hidden_field :holder_id, :value => @holder.id %>
  <br />

  <%= f.submit "Edit Question" %>
<% end %>
```

The form loads the question just fine, as it auto-populates the form with the correct data. However, when I hit submit nothing happens. As an experiment, I changed my update action in the questions controller to redirect to my about_path and after a successful submission I am redirected there. That tells me that the whole process is working, but the data isn't being changed.

Here is my update action:

```
def update
        @question = Question.find(params[:id])
        if @question.update_attributes(params[:holder])
            redirect_to holder_path(@question.holder_id) 
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end
```

What would cause this or how would you begin to trouble shoot this issue?

Comment: @Rob, sorry. That was from me trying something else using a form_tag. I'm pretty sure, I want a form_for.

Comment: So what's the problem, exactly? I mean, how can you tell that something's wrong? Also, are you watching the server log for errors or warnings?

Comment: The DB isn't being updated. Nothing in the server log.

Comment: `params[:holder]` seems suspicious. Shouldn't that be `params[:question]`? In the server log, you should be able to see exactly what parameters are being passed to your update action.

Comment: Just a sanity check, but does params contain the data you think it does? What should it look like?

Comment: You're right! I should probably vow to never copy/paste again! Quick question though: I don't have anything in my server log when I run 'rails s' should I see it there or do I need to look in development.log? even that only has the id in it not the full params.

Comment: You should definitely see rails s spit out lots of messages to your terminal about the request starting and stopping, parameters received, status of the response, and an echo of each database command. I'm sure Rails has a way to turn off logging, but I've actually never done that. Maybe someone else can chime in. Peruse your config/application.rb and config/environments/development.rb for logging oddities? Or a logging-related item in config/initializers.